# PHP windows-1251 codepage and json_encode

Tags: php, json

[PHP 5.6.0RC4] I have json - $json='{msg:"Привет мир!"}' in windows-1251 codepage. $j=json_decode($json, 1); $j['msg']=="Привет мир!". Ok. $json2=json_encode($j); $json2 is null. WTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, it isn't `null` but `false`. And that's just [how it's documented](http://php.net/json_encode):

> All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

... and:

> Returns a JSON encoded string on success or FALSE on failure.